# Apply PromiseJS to this situation

Tags: javascript, promise, browserify

I've just started using js modules with node, require and browserify and trying get code to work, that was originally in a single script.

I'd also like to start using promisejs but am unsure how to apply it in this situation.

All the require browserify parts seem to work so I'll leave that out all the none relevant bits for simplicity.

In the one module I have something like this

```
module.exports.api = function(){

var getCurrentProcessInstanceTask = function getCurrentProcessInstanceTask(options) {
      if (!currentProcess || !currentProcess.id) {
        throw new Error("no currentProcess is set, cannot get active task");
        return;
      }
      var processInstanceId = currentProcess.id;

      jQuery.get(hostUrl + "service/runtime/tasks", {
          processInstanceId: processInstanceId
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
          currentProcess.tasks = data.data;

          if (options && options.callback) {
               options.callback(data.data);
          }
        });
    }

return {
 getCurrentProcessInstanceTask: getCurrentProcessInstanceTask
}

}
```

Then in the other module I have something like this

```
    var Api = require('./api');

    module.exports.view = function(){

     var api = Api();

     var setupEmbeddedView = function setupEmbeddedView(url, tmpl) {
          tmpls.renderExtTemplate({
            name: tmpl,
            selector: targetDiv,
            data: {
            url: url,
            width: iframeTargetDiv.width(),
            height: iframeTargetDiv.height()
          },
            callback: function() {
              jQuery('#taskFormFrame').load(function(e) {
                console.log("taskFormFrame load fired!");

              });

            }
          });
        },
    showCurrentTaskForm = function showCurrentTaskForm() {
          console.log("mark");
          api.getCurrentProcessInstanceTask({
            callback: function(tasks) {
              setupEmbeddedView(getTaskFormUrl(tasks), 'showTaskForm');
            }
          });
        }

    return {
     showCurrentTaskForm: showCurrentTaskForm

    }

    }
```

calling showCurrentTaskForm in another module where view is required results in the api.getCurrentProcessInstanceTask part being executed but setupEmbeddedView never seems to get called.

I'm very confused about why maybe someone can explain.

Also I'd like an example of how I would apply promisejs in this particular case instead of using callbacks to chain functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current version of jQuery does not fulfill the Promises/A+ specification. I would recommend the use of a separate promise library, such as [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

Each function that runs an asynchronous block of code should return a promise.

Looking at your code, the `getCurrentProcessInstanceTask` and thus it should return a promise.

Since you are using `jQuery.get()` which returns a jQuery promise, you will have to let bluebird assimilate that promise to create a proper promise chain.

```
var getCurrentProcessInstanceTask = function getCurrentProcessInstanceTask() {

    if (!currentProcess || !currentProcess.id) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("no currentProcess is set, cannot get active task"))
    }

    var processInstanceId = currentProcess.id;

    return Promise.resolve(jQuery.get(hostUrl + "service/runtime/tasks", {processInstanceId: processInstanceId})
      .then(function(data){
        console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        currentProcess.tasks = data.data;
        return data.data;
      });
    );
}
```

To run it sequentially, just modify the `showCurrentTaskForm` function to call the api function and `.then()` the returned promise.

```
showCurrentTaskForm = function showCurrentTaskForm() {
    console.log("mark");
    api.getCurrentProcessInstanceTask()
      .then(function(result){
        setupEmbeddedView(result, 'showTaskForm');
      })
      .catch(function(e){
        //handle the error
      });
}
```